# centering content within a centered div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div inside a div which has content in it (content created dynamically) I have gotten the child div to center vertically but can't vertically center the content inside. I am using Bootstrap.

```css
.main { 
  position: relative;
  min-height: 600px; 
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

#content { 
  position: absolute; 
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 60%;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%) 
}

#content p {
  position: relative; 
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="main">
    <div id="content">    
      <p> text content </p> ( this is inputted by Wordpress/post )
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: you can just calc(50% - (height of div/2))

Comment: What determines the height of `#content`?

Comment: nothing determines its heght aside from the content that gets put inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flexbox:

```css
.main { 
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#content { 
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#content p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="main" style="">
        <div id="content">              
            <p> text content </p>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: that's the problem I currently have, the child div is centered but the content inside isnt

Comment: @user3550879 do you want to center the content vertically too?

Comment: exactly, I have the content div centered fine, but without the content inside centered it doesn't look centered.

Comment: that edit seemed to work, does the flex property have good cross broswer compatibility

Comment: @user3550879 Look at Can I Use of flexbox: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

The better solution will always be to use flexbox which comes out of the box in CSS3.

Just use the following class:

```
#content p {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    color: #000;
}
```

Alternatively,

You can put the min-height of the class "main" to a 150% instead of 600px.

```
    .main { 
       position: relative;
       min-height: 150%; 
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0; padding: 0;
    }
```

That would be the easiest solution.

Comment: this puts the the text at the top of the div and the div at the top of the page not in the center

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a style something like this, bootstrap don't have that kind of functionality, its up to the user do the job.

```
.center {
  margin: auto;
  height: 65%;
}
```

Hope this help